# GitHub for Mac - Adding Files

Tags: macos, github

My commit generates the following error:

```
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   "Icon\r"
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I am unable to locate Icon\r and typing "git add Icon\r" into Terminal is unsuccessful.  Why is this happening?  Is there a way to add this file to source control from within the GitHub for Mac GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried "git add *" in the directory of your git repository? This should add all the un-added files to the repository. After that you can do your commit.

Comment: No problem. Glad I can be of help.